# How to ignore a file in a Git repository without .gitignore nor a global setting?

Tags: git

I try to add a temporary-but-not-so-temporary file to a Git repository without adding it to the index. I don't want to add it to a .gitignore nor to a file like ~/.gitignore_global because it would just apply for a specific repository.

Is there any way to ignore a file to be indexed in a specific repository without indexing the very fact that I want to ignore it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place the ignore patterns in `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` so that it will be applicable to only the repo and not every repo.

From the manual:

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do
>   not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary
>   files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s
>   workflow) should go into the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid running `git add` on the file you don't want in your repository or...

Local per-repo rules can be added to the .git/info/exclude file in your repo. These rules are not committed with the repo so they are not shared with others. This method can be used for locally-generated files that you don’t expect other users to generate, like files created by your editor.

Comment: You could put the file as a pattern in your git excludes file. ($GIT_DIR/info/exclude or the file location specified by core.excludesfile)